# Gets error "Cannot get CSRF" when trying to install jenkins-plugin using ANSIBLE

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-plugins, csrf

I am using ANSIBLE to install jenkins on CENTOS.
The installation works fine but when it comes to the task of installing plugin, i get the following error.

```
fatal: [jenkins]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "details": "Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>", "failed": true, "msg": "Cannot get CSRF"}
```

The code is as follows.

```
- name: Install jenkins 
rpm_key:
state: present
key: https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key

- name: Add Repository for jenkins
  yum_repository:
    name: jenkins
    description: Repo needed for automatic installation of Jenkins
    baseurl: http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable
    gpgcheck: yes
    gpgkey: https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key

    #Pre requisite: add key and repo
- name: Install jenkins
  yum:
    name: jenkins
    state: present

#Start/Stop jenkins
- name: Start jenkins service
  service:
    name: jenkins
    state: started

#Start jenkins on startup
- name: Start jenkins on boot
  shell: chkconfig jenkins on

- name: Install build-pipeline
  jenkins_plugin:
    name: build-pipeline-plugin
    notify:
      - "restart jenkins-service"
```

Comment: How do you connect to the internet? Any proxy, company firewall?

Comment: I am on company network. There is no proxy or firewall in this setup that I am aware of. I can try it from my home pc, just to test.

Comment: Related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72220756/configure-ansible-playbook-to-skip-jenkins-initial-setup

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to wait between starting up jenkins and trying to install the plugin. The `jenkins_plugin` requires a running and working jenkins installation, so you should do a wait between `Start jenkins service` and `Install build-pipeline`:

```
- name: Wait for Jenkins to start up
  uri:
    url: http://localhost:8080
    status_code: 200
    timeout: 5
  register: jenkins_service_status
  # Keep trying for 5 mins in 5 sec intervals
  retries: 60
  delay: 5
  until: >
     'status' in jenkins_service_status and
     jenkins_service_status['status'] == 200
```

Comment: This helped offcourse but I had to do a little more than this. Jenkins 2.0+ has a startup wizard, you have to make sure that wizard is skipped. Also it asks for InitialPassword, that has to be skipped too. I skipped these two things and added the suggested delay, then the request to install plugins was served. If we do not skip the "initialPassword", jenkins will never respond with 200, it always will respond 404  and the above wait will never pass.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanUlHaq how were you able to skip the 'InitialPassword'? I could not find any option in the config file to do that

Answer (score 3):

In order to skip the startup wizard, I found this (offcourse googling)

```
- name: Jenkins Skip startUp for MI
  lineinfile:
    dest=/etc/sysconfig/jenkins
    regexp='^JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS='
    line='JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"'
  register: result_skip_startup_wizard
```

Comment: Where did you put it? thought of geerlingguy.jenkins -> main.yml -> in variable setup section?

Also I get the error /etc/sysconfig/jenkins does not exist. Which path do I need?

Answer (score 0):

I think all the solutions are valid for specific cases. I want to add the correct way to modify a systemd service unit, if it's your case. We need to create the override file first:

```
[Unit]
Description=Jenkins Controller

[Service]
# Add JVM configuration options
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"
```

You can include as much arguments as you need to override the defaults. (Check [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/) for complete documentation). In this case, I'm only including the `jenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false` option.
Then copy it to destination with ansible:

```
  - name: Override Jenkins deamon file
    become: yes
    copy:
      src: "daemon/override.conf"
      mode: 0600
      dest: /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/
```

The mode should be `0600`, not `0644` as created when we execute `systemctl edit jenkins.service`. Check official [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/systemd-services/).

This can be done before installing jenkins, after that, ansible will execute:

```
  - name: Ensure jenkins
    become: yes
    apt:
      name: jenkins
      update_cache: yes
```

Or similar, depending on your OS. This was tested under ubuntu 20. Then the plugins can by installed as the same way as described by the OP.