# Configure Ansible playbook to skip Jenkins Initial setup

Tags: jenkins, ansible

Hello I'm new to writing Ansible Playbooks but I'm trying to have my playbook install Jenkins. It installs Jenkins just fine but the issue becomes that it wants me to do the initial unlock before installing plugins, creating jobs etc. I've seen in here a few times people saying you just need to add this to your playbook and you should be good. When I add it and then run the playbook it still has this issue even if I do it from a brand new server. Wondering what everyone has done to get by this issue. Thanks for your assistance!

Code I've seen from other posts:
[Gets error "Cannot get CSRF" when trying to install jenkins-plugin using ANSIBLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219781/gets-error-cannot-get-csrf-when-trying-to-install-jenkins-plugin-using-ansible)

```
- name: Jenkins Skip startUp for MI
  lineinfile:
    dest=/etc/sysconfig/jenkins
    regexp='^JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS='
    line='JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"'
  register: result_skip_startup_wizard
```

My Playbook

```
---
# jenkins

- name: Create jenkins group
  group:
    name: jenkins
    state: present

- name: Create jenkins user
  user:
    name: jenkins
    group: jenkins
    state: present

- name: Import jenkins gpg key
  rpm_key:
    state: present
    key: http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
    validate_certs: no

- name: Download Jenkins repo
  get_url:
    url: http://get.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins-2.332.3-1.1.noarch.rpm
    dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/

- name: Install java
  yum:
    name: java-11-openjdk
    state: present

- name: Install Jenkins
  package:
    name: /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins-2.332.3-1.1.noarch.rpm
    state: latest

- name: Jenkins Skip startUp for MI
  lineinfile:
    dest=/etc/sysconfig/jenkins
    regexp='^JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS='
    line='JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"'
  register: result_skip_startup_wizard

- name: Start and Enable Jenkins
  systemd:
    name: jenkins
    state: started
    enabled: true

- name: Sleep for 30 seconds and continue with Jenkins buildout
  wait_for: timeout=30
```

For reference this is what I see in the server when I check the file and then when I just grep for the process.
jenkins     8474       1 34 18:29 ?        00:00:20 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080

You can see the changes though do get put in the file as mentioned from above. Which makes me think even after restarting the service its not seeing the new option. I even manually stopped jenkins and then started but it still did not pick it up.

JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"

Comment: Well, did you check `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` to see what is in there? Did you look in whatever startup script Jenkins uses to see if it makes reference to `$JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS`?

Comment: From what I know the Jenkins configuration file, when installed via a package manager is `/etc/default/jenkins`, not `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`.

Comment: @mdaniel I should have stated it out better but yes the /etc/sysconfig/jenkins does have the options in it. That was the last line in my question has what is in the file for the java_opt section. I'm looking at the startup script for jenkins and I do see that that line is not provided within there. I'll have to see why its not reading the sysconfig/jenkins or I can just try updating the start script itself.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε there is no file within /etc/default so that wouldn't apply here

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε and @forest0918 AFAIK. it is `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` for CentOS and family whereas it is `/etc/default/jenkins` for Ubuntu bros.

Comment: @forest0918 I updated the other post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219781/gets-error-cannot-get-csrf-when-trying-to-install-jenkins-plugin-using-ansible/) with a better way to modify a unit file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late here but I figured I'd leave a comment in here as well as I discovered when I was testing that the setup depended on the version of Jenkins you were attempting to install. Versions I tested are the comment lines above the code.
On the latest line it is just an assumption on my part not a guarantee.

```
# testing for jenkins 2.319.1
- name: Jenkins Skip startUp for MI
  lineinfile:
    dest=/etc/sysconfig/jenkins
    regexp='^JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS='
    line='JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"'
  register: result_skip_startup_wizard

# below works for 2.332.1 or latest
- name: Jenkins Skip startUp for MI
  lineinfile:
    dest=/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service
    regexp='^Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true'
    line='Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"'
  register: result_skip_startup_wizard
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to help me though. Could you please take a look at my code (https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/17398/unable-to-install-jenkins-plugin-via-ansible) and tell me if I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: I'm not sure how you got that far as I cloned your repo and ran it on a 20.04 ubuntu machine and the first thing I ran into was a handler error with start jenkins [link](https://github.com/redbilledpanda/roles/blob/WIP/JenkinsInstaller/tasks/InstallJenkins.yaml#L33). My bad for not posting the final playbook but I added a section to stop jenkins as soon as it was installed waited after that to ensure it is then did the line change and started jenkins. I got the following output when I implemented those changes.

Comment: ● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-02-08 21:37:27 UTC; 1min 38s ago
   Main PID: 39516 (java)
      Tasks: 38 (limit: 1143)
     Memory: 148.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
             └─39516 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080

20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: so the gist of what you did was 1. Stop Jenkins right after it gets installed. 2. Make the line change. 3. Start Jenkins. Is that correct? Were you able to get the plugin installed with this change?

Comment: I've changed my sequence the way you describe. BTW even before I made this change, I was able to get to the point where I keep getting the 403 Forbidden error. I think you were using branch `master` when you should be checking out branch `WIP`. I will merge once I resolve this.
So I embedded you suggestion and I am now stopping Jenkins right after I install it, make the line change in the config and then I start it. Post that I explicitly wait for the service to be up and accessible by waiting for a status of 200. Yet that never happens.